# grid is not loading after edit

Tags: jqgrid

1)I am using JQGrid I am able to edit the roa and post the data but the grid is not loading after submit.I know I am missing something but not sure what is.I looked the forum and google around but no result.Any help would be appriciated.Below is the code for your reference

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#g-grid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                url:  '${createLink(controller: 'response', action: 'listRequestsAsJSON')}',
                   colNames: ['Entry Type', 'Life Cycle Status','Start Date','End         Date','Key      Stakeholder Publish'
                                  ,'Remarks','RoadmapGroup','EventStatus'],
                      colModel: [
                                     {name:'roadMapEntryTypeCode',index:'roadMapEntryTypeCode', editable:true,
                                         edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:initdropdownlist('LIFECYCLE')}},
                                  {name:'lifeCycleStatusCode',index:'lifeCycleStatusCode',editable:true,
                                    edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:initdropdownlist('LIFECYCSTAT')}},
                                     {name:'roadMapEventStartDate',index:'roadMapEventStartDate',editable:true,
                                         formatter:'date',editoptions:{dataInit:datePick}},
                                    {name:'roadMapEventEndDate',index:'roadMapEventEndDate',editable:true,
                                               formatter:'date',editoptions:{dataInit:datePick}},
                                  {name:'keyStakeholderPublisherCode',index:'keyStakeholderPublisherCode',editable:true,
                                    edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:initdropdownlist('KEYSTAKEPUB')}},
                               {name:'roadMapEventRemarksText',index:'roadMapEventRemarksText',editable:true,
                                        edittype:"textarea",editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"20"}},    
                               {name:'roadMapGroupName',index:'roadMapGroupName',editable:true
                                   ,editoptions:{size:10}},
                               {name:'roadMapEventStatusCode',index:'roadMapEventStatusCode',editable:true,
                                       edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:initdropdownlist('EVENTSTAT')}}    
                           ],  
                  pager: jQuery('#g-pager'),
                  ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {    
                                jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
                                        {
                                    closeAfterEdit:true,
                                    afterSubmit: function(response,postdata){
                                        var json=response.responseText;
                                        var result=eval("("+json+")");
                                        return [result.status,result.message];},
                                    editCaption: "Edit LifeCycle Roadmap",
                                    bSubmit: "Save",
                                    bCancel: "Cancel",
                                    bClose: "Close",
                                    saveData: "Data has been changed! Save changes?",
                                    bYes : "Yes",
                                    bNo : "No",
                                    bExit : "Cancel",
                                    reloadAfterSubmit:true
                                        });},
                  viewrecords: true,
                  gridview: true,    
                  editurl:'${createLink(controller: 'response', action: 'updateAssetLifecycleRoadmap')}'+"?AssetId="+${assetInstance?.id}
                });    
        });
        datePick = function(elem){jQuery(elem).datepicker({dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"});};



        $("#bedata").click(function(){
             var gr = jQuery("#g-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
              if( gr != null ) jQuery("#g-grid").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false});
              else alert("Please Select Row");
              });
        initdropdownlist = function(colName) {
               var options = ":";
               $.ajax({
                      async: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '${createLink(controller: 'response', action: 'getDropDownList')}?' + "sel=" + colName,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8″,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(dropDownListMap) {
                              for (var i = 0; i < dropDownListMap.option.length; i++) {
                                options +=";"+dropDownListMap.option[i].value + ":" +dropDownListMap.option[i].label;
                                  }   
                              }
                });
               return options;
        }
```

2)The other thing is with the edit button,there is no action fired on clicking the button,any idea?

```
<input type="BUTTON" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#unmatchedgrid').setGridParam("ur url and params here" )
jQuery("#g-grid").trigger('reloadGrid')
```

from the second time you load the grid by fetching the selected parameters (if any)